# Programmatically adding a view and gesture - "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: swift, swift3, uipangesturerecognizer, unrecognized-selector

I'm able to call the "handleTap" function when I remove the sender, but as soon as I add the `sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer` back in, I get this error: `unrecognized selector sent to instance`. I can't figure it out!

```
class DrawingViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

var newlyAddedSticker = UIImage() {
    didSet {
        makeNewSticker()
    }
}

func makeNewSticker() {
    let newSticker = UIImageView(image: newlyAddedSticker)
    view.addSubview(newSticker)

    let myPanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
    myPanGesture.delegate = self
    newSticker.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    newSticker.addGestureRecognizer(myPanGesture)
}

func handleTap(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    print("hi")
}

}
```

Comment: `UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))` and `func handleTap(_ panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {`

Answer (score 1):

the problem is your didn't specify selector

```
 let myPanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.handleTap))

func handleTap() {
    print("hi")
}
```

hope this will help